# Why some time java don't catch the error?

Tags: java, error-handling

I have a code snippet like,

```
try{
    Util.getType(Id);
}catch (DataServiceFault e){
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);

        %>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                location.href = 'developer.jsp';
            </script>
        <%
}
```

Some times it catches this exception and some times it doesn't. Why is that? All the times log says that there is a DataServiceFault.

Comment: how do you know it doesn't catches it everytime?

Comment: Because it does not go to statements under catch

Comment: then how do you know its `DataServiceFault` error

Comment: Does the log say the exception is thrown from that line? What does the stack trace say?

Comment: all the case same error in the logs.

Comment: If there's an exception other than a DataServiceFault, it won't get caught and it won't get logged.

Comment: how do you know that DataServiceFault is not thrown somewhere else?

Comment: Its correct but logs says same error

Comment: But if you see the error in the logs, then it's clearly executing the catch block. Or do you log it somewhere else in your code as well?

Comment: better you do.. catch (exception e){e.printStackTraceError(System.out);} and display the stack trace is u r answer

Comment: @gigadot Because code is just for get name. And some cases it catch the error and go in to statements in catch.

Comment: Post a stacktrace to show us where exception.

Comment: To be clear, when you said "All the times log says...", does this mean the line `log.error(e.getMessage(), e);` produces that log "all the time"? If so, it means "all the time" the exceptions are catched.

Comment: I mean that if data in the not in data base.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of what came after "I mean" in your last comment?

Comment: I wrote this code to throw and DataServiceFault if the data is not in the database. Some time if the data not in the database it throw an error and successfully go to statements in the catch clause. Some times not

Comment: OK now I understand but you have not answered my question which may help to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exception names are equal and you don't reach the catch block it could be a class loader problem. In the case two classes have the same package and name are loaded with different class loaders there are not equal for the runtime.